# Not all of my NUnit test methods are visible in Test Explorer

Tags: c#, nunit, execution

I am adding the automation of unity tests with NUnit in order to test the existing home developed C# applications my company is using. If I use two tests, only one of them is visible and run.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional and NUnit v3.11.0 with Nunit3TestAdapter v3.13.0.

I created two classes that implement IEnumerator, as well as two methods that use the data from my test files, simple .csv defined in the above mentioned classes.

```
 // Test 1 - success (ok dates)
public class DonneesTestOK : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(
                        @"C:\GIT_Repo\ndm1001\TestSucces.csv"));

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');
            string psDatesDebut = values[0];

            yield return new string[] { psDatesDebut };
        }

    }
}

// Test 2 - fail (bad dates)
public class DonneesTestPasOK : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
       var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(
                        @"C:\GIT_Repo\ndm1001\TestEchec.csv"));

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');
            string psDatesDebut = values[0];

            yield return new string[] { psDatesDebut };
        }
    }
}
```

I also created two methods to test the main application with the respective data files.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestNUnit
{

    // test 1 - succes (ok dates)
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(DonneesTestOK))]

    public void TestNDM1001OK(string[] psDatesDebut)
    {

        int intCodeRetour = 0x00;
        int expected = intCodeRetour;
        Assert.That(Program.Main(psDatesDebut), Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }

    // test 2 - echec (bad dates)
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(DonneesTestPasOK))]
    public void TestNDM1001PasOK(string[] psDatesDebut)
    {

        int expected = 8;
        Assert.That(Program.Main(psDatesDebut), Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
}
```

Only **TestNDM1001OK**, is visible and run.

Main method declaration is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
...

}
```

As with  tests in other applications, the code should test the main application and generate an output file with the correct data.
I test the application with a series of dates from .csv and the application generates some output files.

---

FIXED:

OK, this is beginner's error.
I compared my VS2017 environment in which both tests worked and VS2019 where one did not work.

Besides "Run All" and "Run..." options in Test Explorer in VS2019, I noticed also the "Playlist" section, in which there was selected the playlist called "PasOK". I wondered why this happened and remembered that on Friday, I created two Playlists but don't remember that I select any of them. In VS2017 nothing was selected and all worked fine. So, I changed the dropdown to "Playlist "All Tests" in VS2019 and now it is working.

Comment: You should still be marking your tests with the `Test` attribute, even if you provide a `TestCaseSource`. You can do so in one line, like so: `[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(whatever))]`.

Comment: I would also recommend you check that `DonneesTestPasOK ` actually returns elements. If you don't yield anything, the test may be discovered, but not run.

Comment: No reason to add `[Test]` to the method. In fact, it's a bit confusing to some users to see it, since it may appear to imply that there are actually n + 1 test cases rather than n. We only __allow__ the extra `[Test]` for backward compatibility. All of the following tell NUnit that a method is a test: Test, TestCase, TestCaseSource.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install MSTest.TestAdapter?I have a similar issue with vs2017

Comment: This is NUnit, so the MSTest adapter would have no impact at all except that it would take time to run and find no tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing any tests for the second method, then the source for that method is not returning any data. In order to find out why, simply debug it's enumerator.

Comment: I just commented out the data section and the test method for test 2 which was the only one that worked. The test 1, which was not visible, is now visible visible and running.  So, it looks only one test can work at the the time, which is strange because some other tests worked fine even though I had 6 or 7 different scenarios. Not the same structure, however.

Comment: I just tried the same project in VS2017 and everything works fine. Is this a bug with VS2019? Strange enough.